# Plot with conditional data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file abc.dat having data set with column "ec", "ev", "eig", "ep". I have to plot E vs x graph. Here the values for x, E and other variables related to this are given below.

[image]

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('/Users/abc.dat')

ec = data[0:,0]              
ev = data[0:,1]           
eig = data[0:,2]
ep = data[0:,3] 
a=(eig-(ec-ev))

A= 5
B=1/eig**2

for x in range(1,500): 
    g=(1/(0.5* np.sqrt(2*3.14)))* np.exp((-(x-eig)**2)/(2*(0.5)**2))
    ep_1=(ep*g)**2
    P=sum(ep_1)
    for i in a:
        if i==0:
               D=1
        else:
            D=0
        e=A*B*P*D 
        plt.plot(x,e)
```

Comment: can you provide`data` ? what is `len(data)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the `plt.plot()` command buried in loops, which is probably not what you are trying to do. You will need `x` to be an array the same size as `e`, and from your question it might have fewer points than you expect since it has shape (409,).

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('/Users/abc.dat')

ec = data[0:,0]              
ev = data[0:,1]           
eig = data[0:,2]
ep = data[0:,3] 
a=(eig-(ec-ev))

A= 5
B=1/eig**2

x = np.arange(len(eig))

g=(1/(0.5* np.sqrt(2*3.14)))* np.exp((-(x-eig)**2)/(2*(0.5)**2))

P=((g*np.broadcast_to(ep, (len(g), len(ep))).T)**2).sum(axis=0)

e=np.where(a==0, A*B*P, 0)

plt.plot(x,e)
```

I am not sure from the question if I have the logic for `P` calculating as you want it to.

Comment: why do you broadcast ep ?

Comment: @Rabinzel, I think each value in `ep` is multiplied by `g` (for each `x` value), squared and summed to get the `P` term. So I am creating an `ep` array for each `x` value. But I'm not 100% if that was the correct calculation.